# Cocos2d Two animations for one sprite

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, sprite-sheet

I animate my character like that :

```
-(void) createHero
{


    _batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Snipe1.png"];
    [self addChild:_batchNode];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Snipe1.plist"];

    //gather list of frames
    NSMutableArray *runAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) 
    {
        [runAnimFrames addObject:
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"run000%d.png", i]]];
    }

    //create sprite and run the hero
    self.hero = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"run0001.png"];
    _hero.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    _hero.position = self.heroRunningPosition;

    //create the animation object
    CCAnimation *runAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:runAnimFrames delay:1/30.0f];
    self.runAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:runAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES]];

    [_hero runAction:_runAction];
    [_batchNode addChild:_hero z:0];
}
```

This works fine an my character is running, but now i want a second animation when he jumps. At the moment i make it like that:

```
-(void)changeHeroImageDuringJump 
{
    [_hero setTextureRect:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"run0007.png"].rect]; 
}
```

But now i want a second plist with a second png, so i get a whole new animation when the character jumps. How can i implement that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, i implemented an AnimatedSprite class that will handle this for me. This way, I add files like so:

```
NSDictionary* anims = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Animations/Character/idle_anim.plist", @"Idle",
        @"Animations/Character/walk_anim.plist", @"Walk",
        @"Animations/Character/run_anim.plist",    @"Run", nil];

CCNode* myNode = [[AnimatedSprite alloc] initWithDictionary:anims 
                      spriteFrameName: @"character_idle_01.png"
                        startingIndex:@"Idle"];
```

Changing the animation is as simple as:

```
[myNode setAnimation: @"Run"];
```

Heres my implementation This is the .h

```
@interface AnimatedSprite : CCSprite
{
    NSMutableDictionary* _spriteAnimations;
    CCAction* _currentAnimation;
    NSString* _currentAnimationName;
    bool _initialized;
}
- (id) initWithTextureName:(NSString*) textureName;
- (id) initWithArray: (NSArray*) animList spriteFrameName: (NSString*) startingSprite startingIndex: (int)startingIndex;
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)anims spriteFrameName:(NSString *)startingSprite startingIndex:(NSString *)startingAnim;

- (void) addAnimation: (NSString*) animationName andFilename: (NSString*) plistAnim;

- (void) setAnimationIndex: (int) index;
- (void) setAnimation: (NSString*) animationName;
@end
```

And this is the .m

```
#import "AKHelpers.h"

@implementation AnimatedSprite

NSMutableDictionary* _spriteAnimations;

- (id) initWithTextureName:(NSString*) textureName
{
    CCTexture2D* texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:textureName];
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];

    if ((self=[super initWithSpriteFrame:frame]))
    {
        _currentAnimationName = nil;
        _currentAnimation = nil;
        _spriteAnimations = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
        _initialized = true;

    }
    return self;
}
- (id) initWithArray: (NSArray*) animList spriteFrameName: (NSString*) startingSprite startingIndex: (int)startingIndex
{
    _initialized = false;
    _spriteAnimations = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Add animations as numbers from 0 to animList.count
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString* anim in animList)
    {
        [self addAnimation: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] andFilename:anim];
        i++;
    }

    if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:startingSprite]))
    {
        _currentAnimationName = nil;
        _currentAnimation = nil;
        [self setAnimationIndex: startingIndex];  
        _initialized = true;  
    }

    return self;
}

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)anims spriteFrameName:(NSString *)startingSprite startingIndex:(NSString *)startingAnim
{
    _initialized = false;
    _spriteAnimations = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];//[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Add animations
    for (NSString* key in anims)
    {
        [self addAnimation: key andFilename: [anims objectForKey: key] ];
    }

    if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:startingSprite]))
    {
        _currentAnimationName = nil;
        _currentAnimation = nil;
        [self setAnimation: startingAnim];
        _initialized = true;

    }
    return self;
}
- (void) dealloc
{
    [_currentAnimationName release];
    [_spriteAnimations release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) setAnimation: (NSString*) animationName
{
    if (![_currentAnimationName isEqualToString:animationName])
    {
        [_currentAnimationName release];
        _currentAnimationName = [animationName copy];

        // Stop current animation
        if (_currentAnimation != nil)
            [self stopAction:_currentAnimation];
        //[self stopAllActions];

        // Apply animation
        NSDictionary* clip = [_spriteAnimations objectForKey: animationName];
        if (clip)
        {
            _currentAnimation = [AKHelpers actionForAnimationClip:clip];
            if (_currentAnimation)
                [self runAction:_currentAnimation];
        }
        else
        {
            _currentAnimation = nil;
        }
    }
}

- (void) setAnimationIndex: (int) index
{
    [self setAnimation: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index]];
}

- (void) addAnimation: (NSString*) animationName andFilename: (NSString*) plistAnim
{
    NSDictionary *clip = [AKHelpers animationClipFromPlist:plistAnim];

    if (clip)
    {
        [_spriteAnimations setObject:clip forKey:animationName];        

        if (_initialized && [_spriteAnimations count] == 1)
        {
            [self setAnimation:animationName];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: i added your two classes in my project but i dont get it how you implement them i have Snipe1.plist Snipe2.plist and Snipe1.png and Snipe2.png. In the plist there are run0001-run0007.png and in Snipe2 is jump0001-jump0007.png. How can i add these two animations now ? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Oh and what is AKHelpers ? Where can i get this ?

Comment: You can find AKHelpers here, http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13851, it has its own plist format for animations. What you do is basically a plist that will reference both texture and coordinates, and then define the frames and duration. You can make your plist similar to the sample found here: https://github.com/anton-nikan/iOS-Animation-Kit/blob/master/Samples/cocos2d/frog-menu-anim.plist

Comment: Actually, i use something like this: https://github.com/anton-nikan/iOS-Animation-Kit/blob/master/Samples/cocos2d/animset-clip.plist . This basically lets me just have a single plist per animation, as opposed to using the whole behavior system in AnimationKit

Comment: Ok i added your classes now to my project (AKHelper and AnimatedSprite) everything compiles fine. Now i added this plist to my project: http://cl.ly/ICJH and tried this implementation: http://cl.ly/ICoI. But my app crashes, why ? whats wrong ? sorry for the link but otherwise there wouldn't be characters left for this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Create two different animation actions for running and jumping. Run those actions on need basis.